# User Authentication in ASP.NET with user data not even readable by admin or man-in-the-middle

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, authentication, membership-provider

Imagine you have an ASP.NET based website that users have to authenticate for to get access. The user data (such as username, password and other information relevant for the website) is stored in a Microsoft Sql database.

I know that it is possible to write an custom membership provider to create an own authentication method.

However, what is the best way to

- ensure that the username and password cannot be intercepted by listening to the network traffic in between the client and the server
- store the data in a way so that only the user himself can access it and not even any administrator is able to see these information

If there is any sort of tutorial, howto, screencast or whatever you can point me to or you have even a simple explanation, that would be great!

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: The system administrator always (and probably should?) has a way to view the data.

Comment: The sys admin shouldn't really have a way to view an unencrypted password - they have no need for that.

Answer (score 5):

To secure the usernames and passwords on the network have your users connect via [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer).

To ensure password can't be read in the database, [hash the passwords](http://www.aspcode.net/Storing-passwords-in-your-ASPNET-application-part-1-1.aspx).

Comment: Indeed, setting the default asp.net membership provider to use Hashed passwords (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordformat.aspx) and disable password retrieval (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.enablepasswordretrieval.aspx). These can easily be set in the web.config (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whae3t94.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned ,Hash the passwords in the database ,and to be safe from mitm attacks always try to use https://